# FormBuilderField not showing the right value (Flutter)

Tags: flutter

I created an Item form where you can input title, description,etc...

When selecting the ngo and submitting the entire form, I don't get what I selected.
And when integrating the validator from the FormBuilderField nothing happens, and the item don't get uploaded.

Any idea how I can fix it?
Thank you in advance for your answers!

Here the code:

```
class NgoSelectorState extends State<NgoSelector> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  String selectedNgo = "Select a charity".tr();
  FormFieldState<List<MapEntry<int, NgoDetails>>>? theField;
  AnimationController? _controller;
  AnimationController? _sizeController;
  Animation? _colorAnimation;

  bool isSelected = false;
  String selectedName = "";

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _controller = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100));
    _sizeController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
      value: 1.0,
      lowerBound: 1.0,
      upperBound: 1.1,
    );

    _colorAnimation =
        ColorTween(begin: Colors.transparent, end: MyTheme.primary).animate(_controller!);

    _controller!.addListener(() {});

    _controller!.addStatusListener((status) {
      if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
        setState(() {
          isSelected = true;
        });
      } else if (status == AnimationStatus.dismissed) {
        setState(() {
          isSelected = false;
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _controller!.dispose();
    _sizeController!.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<NgosBloc, NgosState>(builder: ((context, state) {
      if (state is NgosLoadingState) {
        return const MyCircularProgressIndicator();
      }
      if (state is NgosLoadedState) {
        List<MapEntry<int, NgoDetails>>? ngosList = List.from(state.ngos.entries);
        return FormBuilderField(
          name: 'ngoId',
          decoration: const InputDecoration(
            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: MyTheme.primary)),
            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
            filled: true,
            fillColor: Color(0xAFBFDCFF),
            hintText: "Please select your NGO",
          ),
          builder: (FormFieldState<List<MapEntry<int, NgoDetails>>> field) {
            theField = field;
            return SizedBox(
              height: 300,
              child: ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(),
                physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemCount: ngosList.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  String ngoName = ngosList[index].value.name;
                  String ngoLogo = ngosList[index].value.logo;
                  return AnimatedBuilder(
                      animation: _controller!,
                      builder: (BuildContext context, _) {
                        return Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 17, 10, 17),
                          child: GestureDetector(
                            key: Key('$index'),
                            onTap: () {
                              if (isSelected) {
                                _controller!.reverse();
                                _sizeController!.reverse().then(
                                  (value) {
                                    selectedName = ngoName;
                                    _controller!.forward();
                                    _sizeController!.forward();
                                    return null;
                                  },
                                );
                              } else {
                                selectedName = ngoName;
                                _controller!.forward();
                                _sizeController!.forward();
                              }
                            },
                            child: selectedName == ngoName
                                ? ScaleTransition(
                                    scale: _sizeController!,
                                    child: Container(
                                      width: 200,
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          color: _colorAnimation!.value,
                                          borderRadius:
                                              const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
                                      child: Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                                        child: Container(
                                          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                              Radius.circular(8),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          child: Column(
                                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                            children: [
                                              const SizedBox(
                                                height: 10,
                                              ),
                                              Expanded(
                                                child: CachedNetworkImage(
                                                  imageUrl: '${ngoLogo}_SMALL.jpg',
                                                  placeholder: (context, url) =>
                                                      const CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                                  errorWidget: (context, url, error) =>
                                                      const Icon(Icons.error),
                                                  width: 120,
                                                  height: 100,
                                                  //fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                              const SizedBox(
                                                height: 15,
                                              ),
                                              Expanded(
                                                child: Text(
                                                  ngoName,
                                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                                    color: Color(0xff003087),
                                                    fontSize: 16,
                                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                                  ),
                                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                                  maxLines: 7,
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ))
                                : Container(
                                    width: 200,
                                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                        Radius.circular(10),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    child: Column(
                                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                      children: [
                                        const SizedBox(
                                          height: 10,
                                        ),
                                        Expanded(
                                          child: CachedNetworkImage(
                                            imageUrl: '${ngoLogo}_SMALL.jpg',
                                            placeholder: (context, url) =>
                                                const CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                            errorWidget: (context, url, error) =>
                                                const Icon(Icons.error),
                                            //fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                                            width: 120,
                                            height: 100,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        const SizedBox(
                                          height: 15,
                                        ),
                                        Expanded(
                                          child: Text(
                                            ngoName,
                                            style: const TextStyle(
                                              color: Color(0xff003087),
                                              fontSize: 16,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                            ),
                                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                            overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
                                            maxLines: 7,
                                          ),
                                        )
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                          ),
                        );
                      });
                },
              ),
            );
          },
          /* validator: FormBuilderValidators.compose([
            FormBuilderValidators.required(errorText: "Please select your NGO".tr()),
          ]), */
        );
        
      }
      if (state is NgosErrorState) {
        return Center(child: Text(state.error.toString()));
      }
      return Container();
    }));
  }
}
```

Comment: try using setstate here ` selectedName = ngoName;`

Comment: @griffins thank for your answer :D, I changed FormFieldState<List<MapEntry<int, NgoDetails>>>? theField; to FormFieldState<int>? theField; and added field.didChange(ngosList[index].value.id); in onTap function and it worked for me